# Disable "fat finger" emulation in Chrome in device mode

Tags: google-chrome

When in device mode, Chrome will pretend that the user is taping with a finger and instead of precise clicking, it might click in a small radius around the actual tap location. I'd like to disable it. How to.

It's not even the fact that there's a small radius around the pointer, but the fact that if there's no underlying text or image or something in the area that is being clicked, then it will assume the closest element was clicked which is actually outside that little circle.